# ¿Cómo reemplazar una url con extensión .php con una ruta de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, url, rutas

agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Tengo un sitio web en un hosting, y quiero reemplazar el sitio web con un proyecto de Laravel, para ello necesito reemplazar las viejas urls que se encuentran posicionadas en Google, con rutas de Laravel y mostrar una vista Blade en vez de la vista del sitio actual.

Trate usando una ruta con el nombre del archivo incluyendo la extensión:

**Ruta:**

`Route::get('indices/{destination}', [PageController::class, 'products'])->name('products');`

**Controlador:**

````
        $destination = Destination::where('slug', $destination_slug)->first();
        $destination_id = $destination->id;
        $products = Product::orderBy('price', 'ASC')->where('destination_id', $destination_id)->where('status', 'Publicado')->paginate(9);
        return view('web.products', compact('products', 'destination'));
    }```

el resultado por ejemplo es: https://misitioweb.com/indices/europa.php

Sin embargo cuando elimino del servidor la url original que quiero reemplazar con la url de Laravel, no funciona, dice que el destino no existe.

¿Si es posible hacer esto?, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias.
````

Comment: Estás usando artisan serve? Nginx, apache, xampp?